# How do I 'reset' a theme completely?

Tags: files

I think I have deleted some .css theme files in my local directory by accident and when I delete All the theme's files to re-install and get the original files back, they still aren't there. Is there a way to reset the whole theme folder?

Comment: Why WAS the "theming" tag not appropriate for this question ... And why is "files" (still) a relevant tag (looking at its wiki excerpt)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a core/contrib theme, just download the original and replace the modified version with it.

If it's a custom theme, just restore from whatever backup you have available (or from Trash or your OS's equivalent feature).

If you're wondering if Drupal somehow keeps track of file system changes and might be able to help you restore deleted files - it doesn't (I've yet to come across a framework that would do this).

Comment: To some extent, [Hacked!](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) may be used for this purpose. One needs to define source for his theme, and keep unmodified version there. And voila, list of changes available. Not great, and not module's main purpose, but doable. And sometimes less effort than using git properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GIT, just compare your current branch with whatever you have available to get more details about what happened, and then perform the appropriate GIT action (command) to get back to that "reset" point you're looking for.

As a variation, the [Hacked!](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module might be of some help also (if this question is about a contributed module). I.e to find out what is "currently different from the module on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/). Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the diff module is installed then Hacked! will allow you to see the exact lines that have changed.

As per your "***I think I have deleted***": make sure that you also cleared the appropriate caches  ... it doesn't hurt, but sometimes it helps (and turns out to be "the" solution).

PS: if you're NOT using GIT, then consider the issue you suffer now as a great lesson why you should ...